# Looping over tuple in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm trying to loop over `list of tuples` with 4 elements-> `[("y1", "N", "var1", "x1"), ...]`
And create variable based on value in that `tuple` like this:

```py
for kyoten_num in list_of_kyoten_numbers_days: # List of tuples

    if kyoten_num[1] == 'N':
        cl = 4
    if kyoten_num[1] == 'AA':
        cl = 6

    if kyoten_num[2] == 'var1':
        rw = 9
    if kyoten_num[2] == 'var2':
        rw = 10

    print(cl, rw)
```

But it stops at `var1` and printing this till loop end...

```
4 9
6 9
4 9
6 9
4 9
6 9
```

How could I print something like:

```
4 9
6 9
4 10
6 10
```

????

Comment: Can we see the value of list_of_kyoten_numbers_days?

Comment: [("y1", "N", "var1", "x1"), ("y1", "AA", "var1", "x1"), ("y1", "N", "var2", "x1"), ("y1", "AA", "var2", "x1")]

Comment: If none of your conditions is matching, the variables will remain unchanged in the following loop iteration(s).

Comment: oh! Thanks! I get it! there was a whitespace in my values

Answer (score 1):

If I run the following code (which is just your supplied code together with the value for `list_of_kyoten_numbers_days` in the comments)

```
list_of_kyoten_numbers_days = [("y1", "N", "var1", "x1"), ("y1", "AA", "var1", "x1"), ("y1", "N", "var2", "x1"), ("y1", "AA", "var2", "x1")]


for kyoten_num in list_of_kyoten_numbers_days: # List of tuples

    if kyoten_num[1] == 'N':
        cl = 4
    if kyoten_num[1] == 'AA':
        cl = 6

    if kyoten_num[2] == 'var1':
        rw = 9
    if kyoten_num[2] == 'var2':
        rw = 10

    print(cl, rw)
```

Then the output I get is

```
4 9
6 9
4 10
6 10
```

which is precisely what you said you were hoping for as a result.  As such, I suspect that if you're producing different output you're somehow mistaken as to what's in the `list_of_kyoten_numbers_days`.  (Especially since there's exactly one `print` happening per element of that list...)

Answer (score 1):

if possible Can you re validate the tuple declaration, like this:

```
list_of_tup = [("y1", "N", "var1", "x1"),("y2", "AA", "var2", "x1")]

for kyoten_num in list_of_tup:

    if kyoten_num[1] == 'N':
        cl = 4
    if kyoten_num[1] == 'AA':
        cl = 6

    if kyoten_num[2] == 'var1':
        rw = 9
    if kyoten_num[2] == 'var2':
        rw = 10`enter code here`

    print(cl, rw)
```